# CodeIgniter restricted page for admin users only

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am using Code Igniter for a web project.

I have two different users, a basic user and an admin user.

I differentiate the admin user with the basic user simply by having a column in my database called admin which equals to "Yes" or "No"

I have two controllers one controller is purely for login authentication (login.php) purposes, the other is for webpage management etc (site.php).

I am wanting to make pages available to admin users only. This is a snippet of my code from my login controller which currently redirects my users upon successful login as well as setting session data too..

```
   if ($this->input->post('btn_login') == "Login")
   {
        //check if username and password is correct
        $usr_result = $this->login_model->get_user($username, $password);
        if ($usr_result) //active user record is present
        {
             //set the session variables
             $sessiondata = array(
                  'username' => $username,
                  'loginuser' => TRUE
             );
             $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
             if($usr_result->admin == 'Yes')
                  redirect("site/admin");
             else
                  redirect("site/agent");
        }
```

This is a snippet of my main controller which manages my pages etc (site.php):

```
public function admin(){
        $data["title"]="My Admin";
        $this->load->model("notifications");

        if ($this->session->userdata('loginuser')){
            $this->load->view("site_header");
            $this->load->view("site_nav");
            $this->load->view('adminpage', $data);
            $this->load->view("site_footer");
        } else {
            redirect('site/restricted');
        }
    }

    public function restricted(){
        $this->load->view("restricted");
    }
```

Now as you can see from my snippet above for the method admin() i have a if statement to only logged in users to log into this page else the restricted page is shown.

How would I change this code to allow only a user who has the column admin = Yes to access this page only? As currently all my users admin or not can access this page.

I hope this makes sense, thank you in advance!

Comment: Normally I save the `user_id` at session after login. I make a query with user_id which will give me the user information.Now I check  if this user_id has access at this method or controller.I suggest to use @bandrei2408 answer.You can store `user_id` instead of `username` at session.Others solution also good

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the admin result to the session data array

So if the user is an admin you would just add

```
 if($usr_result->admin == 'YES'){
      $admin = true;
 }else{
      $admin = false;
 }
 $sessiondata = array(
              'username' => $username,
              'loginuser' => TRUE,
              'admin' => $admin
         );
```

Then you would just check for it on the next page

```
 if ($this->session->userdata('admin')){
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, that doesn't quite work :/ .......it still allows a user which is not admin (column admin = "No") to login to this page, unless I'm missing something :/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set it for all actions in the controller, add this contructor to your Controller

```
//If you want to have the user into a variable
private $currentUser; 

public function __construct(){
  $this->load->model('login_model');
  $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
  $usr_result = $this->login_model->get_user_by_username($username);
  if(!$usr_result->admin)
    die; //or redirect to page not available
  //If you want to have the user into a variable
  $this->currentUser = $usr_result;
}
```

Into your login_model create a new method get_user_by_username which will return the user by its username. If you don't have unique usernames, add the id of the user in the session and create a method in your model named get_user_by_id which will return the user by its id.

Hope it is what you are looking for. This way you don't have to set the admin session.

L.E. To what Steven said, modify it like this:

```
$sessiondata = array(
          'username' => $username,
          'loginuser' => TRUE,
          'admin' => $usr_result->admin
);
```

Comment: This code is cleaner than my answer for this page. However, then you have a string instead of a boolean. Which can work as well. A good compromise between the two would be to assign some code to set the value to true or false. Then on the next page you can still just do the if(if ($this->session->userdata('admin')))

Comment: Sorry that i mentioned it in my post, but I couldn't comment on yours (not enough reputation).

Comment: Thank you @StevenDStanton, I shall bear that in mind, in addition I have marked your answer as useful as it gave me the baseline to resolve the issue however bandrei2408 edited answer had given me the answer to my query but thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

In your login function :

```
//set the session variables
$sessiondata = array('user' => $usr_result); //This you'll be able to access all your user info at anytime.
$this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
```

And in your main controller :

```
if ($this->session->userdata('user') && $this->session->userdata('user')->is_admin == "Yes")
```

or, more readable :

```
$myUser = $this->session->userdata('user');
if ($myUser && $myUser->is_admin == "Yes")
```

You don't need to set `'loginuser' => TRUE`. If there is a session, it's because your user is logged in. So you just have to check if the session is set or not to know if your user is logged in or not.

Comment: Thanks for this @AdrienXL a combination of the other answers had answered my question, regardless thank you for your suggestion it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add

```
if($usr_result->admin == 'YES'){
  $admin = true;
}else{
  $admin = false;
}
```

then it should equal corectly.
kasmey